# Is there a directory to filter monsters by multiple criteria?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> [An] [Imp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/imp) Consular [...] possesses [...] the power to change its form into that of any Small or Tiny animal, as per the spell [*beast shape II*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape).

d20PfSRD provides a list of [Animals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals), but there is no convenient feature to filter down further by size. Is there a database that can do that? Or at least a list of all small or tiny animals?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on the d20PFSRD site.  You have several options there, the:

1. [Advanced Monster Search](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/advanced-monster-search)
2. [Monster DB](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/monster-filter) (really just a Google doc, so you can search it using Google sheets tools and/or export to Excel and do it there)

Both of those will do what you need, at various levels of sophistication.

Hero Lab has an Encounter Builder but it only has CR and free-text search.